# Magento 2: How to stop expanding advanced layered navigation tab on a page load?

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

I am getting expanded tabs for all attributes in layered navigation when category page loads.
I want navigation like this on page load
[image]

Does anyone have any idea about it?

Comment: Follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38904633/magento-2-expand-layered-navigation

Answer (score 0):

You need to create

> Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer/view.phtml

to your theme folder.

Now change,

```
data-mage-init='{"accordion":{"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true, "active": false, "multipleCollapsible": false}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this but still showing in opened state